# React slick hover scale issue

Tags: css, reactjs, react-slick

[image: react-slick]

I am making a carousel with react-slick and trying to add hover transition to it. But the picture can only scale in 1 direction.

My css:

```
.carousel {
margin-bottom: 10rem;
margin-left: 3.75rem;
margin-right: 3.75rem;

.slider-container {
    div {   
        img {
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 2px;
            padding-left: 2px;
            transition: transform .3s;
            border-radius: 5px;

            &:hover {
                transform: scale(1.3);
                transition: transform .6s;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

react.js:

```
<div className="carousel">
    <h2> Trending </h2>
    <Slider {...settings} className="slider-container">
      <div>
        <img src={img1} alt=""/>
      </div>
```

Comment: I have tried to add padding top and bottom to the div contained those images and it solved the problem. But is there other way to scale pictures over the neighbor div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
.slick-list {
   overflow: visible;
 }
```

This will overwrite current slick overflow value and allow children to overflow